# Strange situation with Firebase Cloud Messaging's onBackgroundMessage and onMessageOpenedApp methods on an Android device

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

After I write and run the following code:

```
int notificationCounter = 0;

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // Increases the counter when background notification arrives
  notificationCounter++;
  print("background: $notificationCounter");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  // Sets FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  String? token = await messaging.getToken();
  print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");

  // Code that runs when the application starts or clicks
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Message opened in the app: ${message.messageId}');
    // Increases the counter when notification is turned on in the app
    notificationCounter++;
    print(notificationCounter);
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

When I use the app in background mode on an Android device, I send the below request to FCM:

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"f48SKHpXT1SBCE2VBdJX3r:APA91bEZwrAB6521mVFwHk7JLHrmLf71QYeg0lRoxxhyeSyl8vKfK5Hyt_WBGH6ino-ZZyRfVP5zRNsC5ra2iCD8ZnJ2Y238usoA9tRC6hHrSjQo2oq9fZPFmx5aNmIyQB9Way9_0EJP",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM v1 HTTP API notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      },
      "android": {
        "priority": "high"
      },
      "apns":{
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "sound": "default",
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

When I send the first request it says "background:1" in the debug console, when I send the second request it says "background:2".
After that, when I open the application notification, I expect "onMessageOpenedApp: 3" in the debug console, but it says "onMessageOpenedApp: 1". I can't understand the logic behind it. I'm actually trying to update the application badge. I prepared such an example to explain it easily.

You can use the code I wrote in an application with Firebase configuration by copying it directly and send the request I specified via Postman. What is the reason for this anomaly?